Relation between ExpTime vs Pspace
Are there any EXPTIME-COMPLETE problems that cannot be proven to be PSPACE-COMPLETE?

No one knows.  While it is conjectured that PSPACE $\ne$ EXPTIME, no one has any proof.  In other words, it is consistent with all of our state of knowledge that PSPACE = EXPTIME.  In particular:

If PSPACE = EXPTIME, then every EXPTIME-complete problem is also PSPACE-complete.

If PSPACE $\ne$ EXPTIME, then every EXPTIME-complete problem is not PSPACE-complete.


No one knows which of those two cases is true.
See, e.g., Why do we believe that PSPACE ≠ EXPTIME?.
